# q project structure, files, modules, testing and github

Tags: kdb

I created a project with 2 folders `src/` and `test/`. The `src/` directory contains 1 file for each module, and all functions in a given file are prefixed with

```
\d .mymodule
```

The `test/` directory contains some tests using the QCumber framework

My problem is, when I want to call one of my functions, be it from a quke test or from the scratchpad, the process does not find my function even when fully qualified:

```
.mymodule.myfunction[]
```

I have to generate the modules from my .q files (in kx developer personal edition: right click / New / Module from Q file) and then that works. But that is very cumbersome because I need to delete/recreate the modules each time I update the source code in a file.

#1 My first question would be: How do I get the q interpreter to find my functions in the .q files, and avoid generating the modules

#2 My second question is: Should I altogether forget about having the .q files and just work with the modules?

I don't like it so much as I like grouping small functions in one file. Also pushing a module to github creates a different folder organisation. Basically instead of having 5 files in the `src/` directory, I end up with 60 files in several folders under `/kxscm/module/.mymodule/qfn`

So would be grateful to get some input on how to address those issues around the q files and modules in a q project hosted on github and run/developed in kxdeveloper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use q/kdb from command-line/terminal. Check existing projects nothing there relies on FD products. No real systems really use it in production.

You can use any directory structure you wish. You load your source files with:

```
\l path/to/your/code.q
\l path/to/different/library.q
```

or

```
system "l /some/directory/file.q"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well after approaching Kx and the lack of solution, I guess you actually have the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick look into KX developer couple of months ago.

What I gathered from there is that for regular KDB development, it was not the best. The modules weren't intuitive and as you said to cause problems when you try to use them anywhere else other than KX developer. There might be a solution around it and probably fastest response would be messaging KX directly and asking their opinion on it.

If you are trying to use KX developer with GitHub then would use KX developer only for checking in and version control rather than actual development. Otherwise, I would steer clear of it. Consider it as an Apple product, it works better if everything tech you use is Apple.